# How to store values from one list to the other list at specific attribute?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two lists. I want to store the data from both lists to a single list in angularjs.

I have tried using for loop for assigning values but it does not seem to be working.

```js
$scope.CustomerSize_Value = [];
$scope.CustSizeAttrib_Id = [];

$scope.StoreAttributeList = {
  'customerSizeAttribute_Id': 0,
  'customerSize_Value': "",
};
```

Here i want to store the values from `CustSizeAttrib_Id` to the `StoreAttributeList.customerSizeAttribute_Id` and values from `CustomerSize_Value` to the `StoreAttributeList.customerSize_Value`.

I want the `StoreAttributeList` to be like:

```js
[
  {customerSizeAttribute_Id:1, customerSize_Value:"Hello"},
  {customerSizeAttribute_Id:3, customerSize_Value:"Info"},
  {customerSizeAttribute_Id:65, customerSize_Value:"Foo"}
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How `CustomerSize_Value` and `CustSizeAttrib_Id` look?

Comment: can you make your question clear please?

Comment: That's what I'm asking from you :) In your question you want, basically, "merge" 2 arrays to one. You mention how the output should look (Array of objects) but you didn't mention what the arrays `CustomerSize_Value` and `CustSizeAttrib_Id` contain? Is it object? A number? A string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like essentially a double for loop problem.  Assuming there are no gaps in your arrays and they are the same length, you can do something like this with reduce and you should get the object array that you're looking for.

```
const size = [1,2,3];
const attr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const reduced = (_size, _attr) => {

    return _size.reduce((prev, next, index) => {
        prev.push({
            s: next, a: _attr[index]
        });
        return prev;
    }, []);

}

console.log(reduced(size, attr));

// [{s: 1, a: "a"}, {s: 2, a: "b"}, {s: 3, a: "c"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming both arrays are the same size then you can just use loops to create a new array of objects

````
$scope.CustomerSize_Value = [];
$scope.CustSizeAttrib_Id = [];

$scope.StoreAttributeList = $scope.CustomerSize_Value.map((size, index) =>
{
  'customerSizeAttribute_Id': scope.CustSizeAttrib_Id[index],
  'customerSize_Value': size,
};```
````